# angular 7 route state unable to get passed data

Tags: angular, routes, state

I am using angular 7

Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.16.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.2.15

I use this code to pass data when route to another component

this.router.navigate(['/product'],{state: {token: data.token}});

and try to get token using following code

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("#25"); 
    this.state = this.activatedRoute.paramMap
        .pipe(map(() => window.history.state));
    console.log("#28"); //method 1
    console.log(this.state.token);
    this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart))
                .subscribe((e: NavigationStart) => {
        this.state = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
        console.log("#33"); //method 2
        console.log(this.state.token);
    });

}
```

the console show

## 25 product.component.ts:25:10

## 28 product.component.ts:28:10

undefined

both method cannot get data back, how can I do it right?

Comment: Thansks for the help from tano, Sudipto Mukherjee. Let me summarize the solution for this problem. To get state from routed compoent, this.state = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state; will work in constructor but not ngOnInit. this.state = history.state; will work in ngOnInit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The activatedRoute.paramMap is an Observable. If you want to get its data use this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap
But for states this should work:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.state = history.state;
   ...
}
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: "this.router.getCurrentNavigation(...) is null"

Comment: I read several discuss about this state feature in angular 7.2+, but cannot get it work

Comment: yes, the state is cleared when the navigation ends,so you can get it from history:

Comment: this.state = history.state;

Comment: yes, history.state works. my situation is component A route to component B. When B execute ngOnInit, navigation already ends. So, history.state is the only way to access passed state, right?

Comment: yes, it is. It depends on your requirements. If this token is changing from time to time you can pass it this way, but you can use a service(store) for it. Consider that if the user reloads the page, the token will be missing since it is not saved, even if the user goes back(with browser back button, for example) to your page, the token won't be there. So I'd use singleton service to pass data, but it works as well in one direction.

Comment: `<a routerLink="./publishedbook" state="{ id:1 , name:'Two States'}">Two States</a>`

**in my case console is giving the following response**

`{0: "{", 1: " ", 2: "i", 3: "d", 4: ":", 5: "1", 6: " ", 7: ",", 8: " ", 9: "n", 10: "a", 11: "m", 12: "e", 13: ":", 14: "'", 15: "T", 16: "w", 17: "o", 18: " ", 19: "S", 20: "t", 21: "a", 22: "t", 23: "e", 24: "s", 25: "'", 26: "}", navigationId: 3}`

**how to get it in object form or simple json.**

Comment: pls. try JSON.stringify to set and JSON.parse to get this object.

Answer (score 11):

I am using angular 8

Component from where I am routing

```
this.router.navigate(['/ledger-card'], { queryParams: { branchId: '10', loanAcc: '2738'}});
```

Component where I am receiving the routed data

```
const param = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap;
    if  (param.get('branchId')) {
      const branchId =  param.get('branchId');
      const loanAcc = param.get('loanAcc');
    }
```

** Make sure you import ActivatedRoute

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

**In Order to pass data between components without using Query Parameter**

Component from where you are routing

```
this.router.navigate(['/hello'],{state: {data: '24'}});
```

Component where you are receiving

```
const s = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
```

Please make sure you execute the receiving code inside the constructor as its scope ends there. You will be unable to fetch the data on ngOnInit().

Working Sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fygew5

Comment: Thanks, this works but queryParams will be shown in url. I would like to find a way to make it hidden. Token is suppose to be a secret

Comment: @VincentChen I have updated my answer accordingly. Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 4):

I am using angular latest version and this is how I did it 
**P.S:** This method works even outside constructor scope

**Component from where you are routing**

```
this.router.navigate(['/hello'],{state: {data: '24'}});
```

**Component where you are receiving**

```
import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: LocationStrategy) {}

const s = this.location.getState();
```

Comment: This works for me with Angular version 15! `this._router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;` did not work anymore, `state` was always `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me to get the state from Router in constructor

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {
   const state = this._router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
   console.log(state);
}
```